# Umbraco Richtext Editor not loading

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

I've been scratchign my head on this one, hopefully someone can provide some feedback.

Umbraco Version: 4.7.2

**Problem**

A solution I developed for a company is having problem loading the rich text editor. They have a virtual IP solution acting as a proxy for their servers. After debugging on the client we noticed that the editor (tiny mce) was not loading because for some reason it is requesting the script and icons via the IP and not the URL. Obviously the IP is not hardcoded anywhere...

**Need Help...**

The client's IT department insists the configuration is ok; I think they are right, everything else in Umbraco seems to be working correctly. So I need help...

- Is there anyway I can force the editor to be loaded from a specific URL?
- I have experimented with changing the JS on umbraco_client, but the changes do not show when I load the editor. they appear to be cached somewhere (processed by the compressor), I've re-started the app and cleared my cache with no luck. *How can I make my JS Changes be picked up?*

**What I've Tried**

- Setting the document.domain="my-url". No luck.
- Setting the document_base_url on tinyMceConfig.config. Of course this is for links within the editor, so.. no luck

All other changes I've tried are on the JS files on /umbraco_client/tinymce3/, but I can't get them to show.

Any pointers?

Thanks,

-Covo

Answer (score 0):

Is the RTE not rendering within umbraco it self or is the content not rendering on the front end?

This is a very good question - have you tried removing the property and adding again?

Other than what you've tried so far I'm out of suggestions other than the above sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The behaviour is that when it fails to load the RTE, it shows the textarea by default, but without the RTE properties. Regarding your other question, this is actually not related to any particular property; it happens with all Reich text Editor properties.